# How to switch aws profile within a groovy script in Jenkins active choice reactive parameter

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, groovy, kops

I am trying to switch to the aws prod profile (defined in ~/.aws/credentials as jprod) inside a **Jenkins active choice reactive parameter** groovy script.

But nothing seems to work.  So far I've tried setting `AWS_PROFILE` variable and defining a system property with `System.setProperty`

Interestingly enough the aws cli commands with --profile=jprod seem to work.  Is there a way of doing something similar with kops?  Or any other suggestion on how to switch profiles inside the groovy script.

```
//System.setProperty("AWS_PROFILE", "jprod")
System.properties.'AWS_PROFILE' = 'jprod'

//AWS_PROFILE='jprod'
//def AWS_PROFILE='jstage'

def command ='kops get clusters --state=s3://k8s-bucket-state-prod'

def proc=command.execute()
proc.waitFor()       

def output = proc.in.text
def exitcode= proc.exitValue()
def error = proc.err.text

if (error) {
    println "Std Err: ${error}"
    println "Process exit code: ${exitcode}"
    return exitcode
}
return output.tokenize()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer: just had to modify the command to use env:

```
def command ='env AWS_PROFILE=jprod kops get clusters --state=s3://k8s-bucket-state-prod'
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivory Micky for the response. Do you know any way to trigger the same using AWS secret Id and access key ?

Comment: @Arun you just supply those two after `env` instead of the `AWS_PROFILE`. `env` parses all VAR=VALUE pairs until there are no more and then runs the command that follows them.